# Separable Differential Equation, finding the constant C

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the Separable Differential Equation theorem.

According to my textbook, this is the theorem.

A differential equation of the form $dy/dx=f(y)g(x)$ is cal separable. We separate the variables by writing it in the form

$1/f(y) dy =g(x) dx.$

The solution is found by anti differentiating each side with respect to tis thusly isolated variable.

Take question 1.

$dy/dx = x/y $and $y=2$ when $x=1$. Use separation of varaibles to solve the initial value problem. Indicate the domain over which the solution is valid.

Answer:

[image]

I was able to integrate this.  But when I got to second line, I plugged in the respective x and y values and got C=3/2. Why does the author simply the fraction first?

Comment: The constant is different the author used $y^2=x^2+c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author multiplied both sides of the equation by two and absorbed the two into the constant:
$$\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$y^2=x^2+C$$
Using $y(1)=2$:
$$4=1+C \Rightarrow C=3$$
$$\Rightarrow y=\sqrt{x^2+3}$$

If you do it your way you still obtain the same final answer:
$$\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$2=\frac{1}{2}+C$$
$$\Rightarrow C=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow y^2=x^2+3$$
$$\Rightarrow y=\sqrt{x^2+3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2=x^2+2C$$
Then since $y(1)=2$:
$$4=1+2c \implies c=\dfrac 32$$
$$y^2=x^2+3 \implies y=\sqrt {x^2+3}$$

The book used:
$$y^2=x^2+2c=x^2+C$$
$$y(1)=2 \implies C=3$$
They should use another name for the now constant $C=2c$.